# Kotlin reflection: Is it possible to use KProperty1 and omit the class when the type is known through Generics

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I'm working on mass database transformations. There are a lot of data classes, some of them with relationships between each other similar to the ones in SQL databases. These relationships are done by UUIDs, not by nesting data classes.

To lookup up in a list such an ID by some value in another property I use a function called *lookup,* which takes the KProperty1 of the field I have the value for, and the KProperty1 of the field with the ID to be returned:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty1

fun <T> List<T>.lookup(lookup: KProperty1<T, String>, value: String, `return`: KProperty1<T, String>): String? =
  this
    .firstOrNull { lookup.get(it) == value }
    .run { if (this == null) null else `return`.get(this) }
```

Both fields and the lookup value are always of type String in all data classes, and therefore the return value of the lookup function is always String?.

I use it like this:

```
data class Test(
  val ID: String,
  val TEXT: String
  // more fields ...
)

val list = listOf(
  Test("1", "abc"),
  Test("2", "def"),
  Test("3", "ghi"),
  Test("4", "jkl")
)

val result = list.lookup(Test::TEXT, "ghi", Test::ID)

println(result)   // Output: 3
```

The question is: is there a way to omit the class name in the two parameters of the function? Basically something like this:

```
val result = list.lookup(::TEXT, "ghi", ::ID)
```

It could be done with strings, but there is of course the danger of misspelling:

```
val result = list.lookup("TEXT", "ghi", "ID")
```

The reason I ask – besides being curious – is that with thousands of such lookups – and often very long names – it just would look better:

```
val ... = storageLocationWarehouseSubItemList.lookup(StorageLocationWarehouseSubItem::TEXT, "ghi", StorageLocationWarehouseSubItem::ID)

val ... = storageLocationWarehouseSubItemList.lookup(::TEXT, "ghi", ::ID)
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure the answer is no. I’ve never seen any indication that there is ever a situation where you can be lazy about defining a function type with function reference syntax. The closest thing I can think of is this upcoming feature for Enum and sealed class resolution, but it doesn’t mention function references: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16768

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that too (and thank you for the link).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest not requiring `KProperty1` specifically. This is a very specific type and what you really need is just a mapping from `T` to `String`, so a function type:

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.lookup(lookup: (T) -> String, value: String, `return`: (T)  -> String): String? =
    this
        .firstOrNull { lookup(it) == value }
        .run { if (this == null) null else `return`(this) }
```

It works with property references, as your original code, but it also receives function references and lambdas.

Now, answering your question: I don't see a way to do this directly, but because you need to use this a lot, maybe it makes sense to provide additional functions to make it possible:

```kotlin
fun ID(obj: Test) = obj.ID
fun TEXT(obj: Test) = obj.TEXT

val result = list.lookup(::TEXT, "ghi", ::ID)
```

You can have multiple such functions with the same name and they will be properly resolved using the type of the list:

```kotlin
data class Test2(
  val ID: String,
  val TEXT: String
)

fun ID(obj: Test2) = obj.ID
fun TEXT(obj: Test2) = obj.TEXT

val result2 = listOf<Test2>().lookup(::TEXT, "ghi", ::ID)
```

It is far from perfect, but at least it works.